# Inserting picture from user field into table in powerapps

Tags: powerapps

I have created a powerapps app, and inserted data from a SharePoint list. I can get all the text data I require, but I can't get the profile picture from a user. I have a user field, and if I try to insert ThisItem.User.Picture into a text field, a valid URL shows up, linking to the correct image. The image control still remains white.

I have also tried getting the user image, using User().Image. This only shows the placeholder image, not my actual profile picture. Inserting this into a text field yields a base64 string, and decoding this again gives me the placeholder image.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious what the format of the URL that you are seeing from ThisItem.User.Picture looks like. As long as the URL is directly pointing to a valid image file and the user has permissions to view it, it should populate the image control. Would you mind sharing the URL you are seeing?

Comment: Naturally.The link is as follows:
https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com/User Photos/Profilbilleder/{username}_MThumb.jpg

If I go to the URL in a browser, the image is shown, but has to go through login flow if not already logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using O365 or On-Premise SharePoint?
If its O365 then make sure you add the Connection to Office365 Users.

Comment: It's Office 365. I have tried setting up a connection, but the User object from O365 does not contain an image. Have you had it working?